# Parse XML using parsedata() loses login in session in Android

Tags: android, session, networking

I am having an issue with the parseData() java function in android studio.  I need to use it several times in one activity.  The first time it loads, it grabs information from a url and displays the information in a list.  This part works grea but now I need to be able to click on each listing and run the parseData per unit, each item has a unique url that I need to trigger, the url tells the database to decrease qty by one for that item.  When I try to run parseNewData(),the second parseData function, in the file and pass it the unique url, it loses the cookies or does not pass the authorization (login session) so app fails with the error below.  The log of the url returns 302 redirect, I think the login session information is lost or not passing correctly to url, it tries to send back to login activity and then causes a fail on "HttpResponse responseNew = LoginActivity.client.execute(httppost);"

Any help would be great.

> Activity Code

```
package com.mike_scanncer_example.mike_scanner;



import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;
import java.lang.Object;



import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class Search_Result extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler=new Handler();
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String ticket_no="";
    String cname="";
    String order_no="";
    String card_no="";
    String url="";
    Vector<Vector<String>> data =null;
    String [] number=null;
    String [] checkedin =null;
    String [] type=null;
    String auth="";
    String msg="";
    String status="";
     String reply="";
        String mssg="";
        String c_time="";
         boolean f=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ticket_check);

        ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_search);
                back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    Search_Result.this.finish();
                    }
                });


        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.v("bundle", String.valueOf(extra));

        url=extra.getString("url");
        Log.v("LOG", url);

        data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();


        final ListView l1 =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ticket_list);
         dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Search_Result.this,"",
                    "Loading...", true);
        l1.setDivider(null);

        final Thread t =new Thread(new Runnable() {


            public void run() {
                parseData();

            }
        });
        t.start();
        Thread t1 =new Thread(new Runnable() {


            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 try {
                        t.join();
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  

                     mHandler.post(new Runnable() {


                        public void run() {
                        dialog.cancel();


                            if(auth.equals("success"))
                            {
                                Log.v("login-info",auth);
                                number=new String[data.size()];
                                checkedin=new String[data.size()];
                                type=new String[data.size()];
                                for(int j=0; j<data.size(); j++)
                                {   
                                number[j]=data.get(j).get(0);
                                checkedin[j]=data.get(j).get(1);
                                type[j]=data.get(j).get(2);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {


                                if(msg.equals("Please Login First"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Result.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast.makeText(Search_Result.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Toast.makeText(Search_Result.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Search_Result.this);
                                    dialog2.setMessage("Sorry!\nRecord not found.");
                                    dialog2 .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,  final int id) 
                                           {
                                                finish();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    dialog2.show();
                                }


                            }


                        l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int position, long id) {


                            }


                        });


                        }
                    });

            }
        });

        t1.start();

    }


    private void parseData()
    {
         SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser sp = null;
        try {
            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         // Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created.
         XMLReader xr = null;
        try {
            xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader
         MyExampleHandlerGarbageDepot myExampleHandler = new MyExampleHandlerGarbageDepot();
         xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

         // Parse the xml-data from our URL. 
         try {

         String urlToHit = url;

         URL url=new URL(urlToHit);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

        HttpResponse response = LoginActivity.client.execute(httppost);

      // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            InputStream instream = null;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                 instream = entity.getContent();
            }

            xr.parse(new InputSource(instream));



          //HttpPost http=new HttpPost(url.toString());

          //HttpResponse res=client.execute(http);
         // Log.v("response code",""+res);

         // xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    class MyExampleHandlerGarbageDepot extends DefaultHandler
    {



          private Vector<String> singleItem1=null;

     // private boolean Rss = false;    
      //private int i=0;
      // ===========================================================
      // Methods
      // ===========================================================
      @Override
      public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        //this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

      }

      @Override
      public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Nothing to do

      }

      @Override
      public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
              String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {


             if(localName.equals("Reply"))
             {

                auth=atts.getValue("replyCode");
                msg=atts.getValue("msg");
                Log.v("@#@#@",auth);

             }
             else if(localName.equals("Tickets")){



             }
             else if(localName.equals("Ticket"))
             {

                     singleItem1=new Vector<String>();
                 singleItem1.add(atts.getValue("number"));
                 singleItem1.add(atts.getValue("checkedin"));
                 singleItem1.add(atts.getValue("type"));

             }


             }



      /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
      * </tag> */
      @Override
      public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
              throws SAXException {

          if(localName.equals("Tickets"))
          {

          }
          else if(localName.equals("Ticket"))
          {
              data.add(singleItem1);  
          }

      }

     /** Gets be called on the following structure:
     * <tag>characters</tag> */
     @Override
     public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {


     }
    }


    private void parseNewData(String new_url)
    {
         SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser sp = null;
        try {
            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         // Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created.
         XMLReader xr = null;
        try {
            xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader
         MyHandlerGarbageDepot myExampleHandler = new MyHandlerGarbageDepot();
         xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

         // Parse the xml-data from our URL. 
         try {

         String urlToHit = new_url;
         Log.v("test123", new_url);
         URL url=new URL(urlToHit);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

        HttpResponse responseNew = LoginActivity.client.execute(httppost);

      // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = responseNew.getEntity();

            InputStream instream = null;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                 instream = entity.getContent();
            }

            xr.parse(new InputSource(instream));



          //HttpPost http=new HttpPost(url.toString());

          //HttpResponse res=client.execute(http);
         // Log.v("response code",""+res);

         // xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    class MyHandlerGarbageDepot extends DefaultHandler
    {



         private boolean checkin =false;
     // private boolean Rss = false;    
      //private int i=0;
      // ===========================================================
      // Methods
      // ===========================================================
      @Override
      public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        //this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

      }

      @Override
      public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Nothing to do

      }

      @Override
      public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
              String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {


             if(localName.equals("Reply"))
             {

                reply=atts.getValue("replyCode");
                mssg=atts.getValue("msg");
                c_time=atts.getValue("time");
                Log.v("@#@#@",auth);

             }

                if(localName.equals("Checkedin"))
                  {
                 checkin = true;

                 }


      }




      /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
      * </tag> */
      @Override
      public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
              throws SAXException {

          if(localName.equals("Checkedin"))
          {
            checkin=false;
          }


      }

     /** Gets be called on the following structure:
     * <tag>characters</tag> */
     @Override
     public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {

             if(checkin)
             {
                 status = new String(ch,start,length);
             }

     }
    }   




    private  class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
         private LayoutInflater mInflater;

         public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

         }

         public int getCount() {
         return data.size();
         }

         public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
         }

         public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
         }

         public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final ViewHolder holder;


         if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket_list, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();

         holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_num);
         holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_type);
         holder.check_img = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ticket_status);

         convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }
            holder.text.setText(data.get(position).get(0));
            holder.text1.setText(data.get(position).get(2));

            if(data.get(position).get(1).equals("0")){
                holder.check_img.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_inbut));
            }
            else{
                holder.check_img.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checked_in_but));
            }

            holder.check_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(data.get(position).get(1).equals("0")){
                        //Toast.makeText(Search_Result.this,"check",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        url=Config.baseUrl+"checkin/"+Config.eventId+"/"+data.get(position).get(0);

                        parseNewData(url);



                        if(reply.equals("success"))
                            {

                                        if(status.equals("0"))
                                        {
                                            holder.check_img.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_inbut));
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            holder.check_img.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_back));
                                            Toast.makeText(Search_Result.this, "Check out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }
                            }
                            else
                            {


                                    if(mssg.equals("Please Login First"))
                                    {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Result.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        Toast.makeText(Search_Result.this, mssg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    


                                }               
                            }


                    }
                    else{

                        url=Config.baseUrl+"checkinInfo/"+Config.eventId+"/"+data.get(position).get(0);
                        //parseNewData(url);
                        Log.v("LOG", url);

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Search_Result.this);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = builder.setMessage("Ticket is already checked in")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("view details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        String contents = data.get(position).get(0);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Search_Result.this, Ticket_detail.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("ticket_no", contents);
                                        intent.putExtra("event_id", Config.eventId);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                        builder.show();


                    }

                }
            });

                         return convertView;

    }
    }

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    TextView text1;
    ImageButton check_img;
    }


}
```

> OUTPUT ERROR LOG

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: com.mike_scanncer_example.mike_scanner, PID: 2516
>                   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                       at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>                       at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:300)
>                       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1194)
>                       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1189)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.shutdown(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:188)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.shutdown(DefaultClientConnection.java:155)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$PoolEntry.shutdown(SingleClientConnManager.java:445)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:249)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:195)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:332)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>                       at com.mike_scanncer_example.mike_scanner.Search_Result.parseNewData(Search_Result.java:403)
>                       at com.mike_scanncer_example.mike_scanner.Search_Result.access$200(Search_Result.java:63)
>                       at com.mike_scanncer_example.mike_scanner.Search_Result$EfficientAdapter$1.onClick(Search_Result.java:579)
>                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8648', transport:
> 'socket'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is stated in the error output

> NetworkOnMainThreadException

It looks to me like it occurs in your parseData exception here:

```
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

   HttpResponse response = LoginActivity.client.execute(httppost);
```

You cannot make Network calls on the Main Thread. In your onCreate call, instead of the Runnables, I would look at using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It will clean up the code in the onCreate method and gives you an override to use when the call is done (protected void onPostExecute)